# LINKER ERROR 2005/2001 c++, visual studio

Tags: c++

i am learning c++ and i run into a problem i cant fix.

i looked up the errors on docs.microsoft but it doesnt help me that much^^.

the problem:

i defined a struct in "`main.h`" with all variables i need in my program.

i included the main.h in 3 different source files.

-> Error 2005 already defined in `xx.obj`

--> i tried to delete the struct and make all variables `extern` -> another error..

next try:

i made for all `x.cpp` files an own header file with only the variables included (as struct with same name from main.h) i need. now i get a name conflict since all structs are named the same.

i think the fix is to give all structs different names and instantiate them with different names...

main.h

```
    struct hallo {
    int x1;
    .
    .
     int x;
    } h;
    void func1();
void func2();
```

test1.cpp

```
#include main.h
void func1() {h.x1 = ..;}
```

test2.cpp

```
    #include main.h
    void func2() {h.xn = ...;}
```

main.cpp

```
    #include main.h
    func1();
    func2();
```

2 questions:
1. is my solution right?
2. isnt there a smoother way for this? 
i just wanted 1 struct ... :(

sorry for the bad english :D

Comment: Just post your code instead of describing it. Try to make it a [mre]. This is not enough information.

Comment: What's behind those "..."s? Why do you hide things from us? Also, what's with the chaotic indentation that makes your code (and question) harder to read?

Comment: thats fictional code to illustrate my problem because my code is way to big to just post it here

Comment: Post the code that generated the linker error and copy and paste the linker error text _exactly_.  Currently your question reads: _ I had a problem. I solved the problem. Is my solution correct._.. That makes it an XY problem.  Better to present the original problem that to ask for your solution to be reviewed.

Comment: ok sorry. will do it next time. i could fix it. by the answer of john..

Comment: "is my solution right?" - does it compile and link?  No - that that answers that part then.

Comment: You should fix it now, for this time. Make it so that your question actually demonstrates the problem, rather than being "fictional code". You do that by producing a [mcve]. That should be part of your debugging, before resorting to posting here. Help us to help you and remember that your post should stand the test of time and help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not right. Do it like this

main.h

```
struct hallo {
    int x1;
    ...
    int x;
};

extern hallo h;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

hallo h;
```

test1.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
```

test2.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
```

In other words, extern in the header file, not extern in **one** (and only one) of your cpp files.

This really would be explained in any good C++ book. You should try and find one.

Comment: i edited again...cause this example was not really right :D but i think i got you... insead of making an instance right away just do one in all cpp files..right?

Comment: Yes you should only define `h` once. Which is why you have to use `extern` in the header file.